# Can't install Veloeclipse for Liferay Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse, liferay, velocity, liferay-ide, liferay-velocity

I am trying to get syntax highlighting for .vm files in my Liferay Developer Studio IDE, but I am having issues installing [Veloeclipse](http://propsorter.sourceforge.net/).

I went to *Help → Install New Software... → Add...*

For the *Name*, I entered *Veloeclipse* and for the *Location*, I entered *http://propsorter.sourceforge.net/veloeclipse*.

When I tried installing, it came up with this error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I use Liferay IDE and not Liferay Developer Studio... so I'm not able to reproduce your problem... but a first important question is: on which version of Eclipse is based your Liferay Developer Studio Version?

Comment: This will not resolve your problem with Lifeway vs Veloeclipse, but you think about use another editor to edit the velocity files? Like [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [Brackets](http://brackets.io/).